# SonarScanner: Socket Error while uploading report to server

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

Facing a socket error while the report is being uploaded to Sonarqube Server.

```
Can't read file part for parameter report.

Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
```

Here is my environment:

- SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe - 4.3.1.1372
- MSBuild -                  14.0
- SonarQube Server -         6.7.5 (build 38563) with HTTP port
- Java -                     1.8.0_171

Disabling anti-virus scan didn't help. Appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

```
`2018.08.27 05:35:46 WARN  web[AWVXE187nt9Be4C0AACa][o.s.s.w.ServletRequest] Can't read file part for parameter report
java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2911)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3211)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
    at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(ServletRequestWrapper.java:153)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.ServletRequest.readParam(ServletRequest.java:76)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.readParamOrDefaultValue(ValidatingRequest.java:132)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:95)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.internal.ValidatingRequest.param(ValidatingRequest.java:70)
    at org.sonar.api.server.ws.Request.getParam(Request.java:297)
    at org.sonar.server.ce.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:104)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:103)
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceFilter.doFilter(WebServiceFilter.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter$GodFilterChain.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:126)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.MasterServletFilter.doFilter(MasterServletFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:87)
    at org.sonar.server.user.UserSessionFilter.doFilter(UserSessionFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doHttpFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:72)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.SecurityServletFilter.doFilter(SecurityServletFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.requestid.RequestIdFilter.doFilter(RequestIdFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.RootFilter.doFilter(RootFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2864)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:722)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1072)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:140)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:326)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:642)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:183)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293)
    ... 53 common frames omitted`
```

Comment: Do you have any kind of anti-virus software installed? Check those settings and logs.

Comment: I have checked all the logs and also tried disabling the virus scan. It made no difference.